# Modulus of product of numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> Is $$(a\cdot b\cdot c)\mod n$$ equal to $$((a\mod n) \cdot (b\mod n) \cdot (c\mod n))\mod n$$ ?
>
> Is $$\dfrac{((a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot d\cdot e\cdot f\cdot g\cdot h\cdot i)\mod n)}{((a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot d)\mod n)} $$ equal to $$ (e\cdot f\cdot g\cdot h\cdot i)
> \mod n$$?
>    If unequal Then what does this expression simplifies to 
>   $$\dfrac{((a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot d\cdot e\cdot f\cdot g\cdot h\cdot i)\mod n)}{((a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot d)\mod n)}$$

Comment: What does double equals sign mean ?

Comment: == means if they are equal. You check both sides of the expression and if they come out equal you return true else return false

Comment: Quotients with the equivalence relation $x-y \in n\mathbb{Z}$ form a well-defined morphism of monoids (the canonical quotient map) $(\mathbb{Z}, \times) \to (n\mathbb{Z}, \times)$. What does this mean for you question?

Comment: @A---B I have edited the question please check again and answer.

Comment: @A---B I have edited the question please check again and answer.

Comment: @FrancescoCarzaniga I didn't get you please explain more clearly

Comment: Second equality is not true, if I get your notation.

Comment: @A---B Okay Then what is the simplified form of left hand side of second one, i.e. ((a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i)%n)/((a*b*c*d)%mod) what does it simplify to after division?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$(a+sn)(b+tn)=ab+(sb+at+stn)n$$

So shifting factors by a multiple of $n$ shifts the product by a multiple of $n$. This can be generalised to multiple factors in various elementary ways.

When dividing, you have to be aware that eg modulo $6$ you have $2\times 3\equiv 0$, and rules about division generalise most easily when you insist that the factors are all coprime to the modulus. The presence of zero-divisors adds further complications to the issue of dividing by zero or trying to define $\frac 00$.

---

A typical situation in the finite case - take modulo $6$ - is you either have as examples

$$3n\equiv 1$$which has no solution or $$3n\equiv 0$$ which has the three solutions $0,2,4$. Converting these equations into fractions causes problems, but the congruences make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably going to be overkill, but oh well...

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and denote $n\mathbb{Z} :=\{a\times n\, |\, a\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ the set of multiples of $n$. Define the following relation $R$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ : let $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $xRy \iff x-y \in n\mathbb{Z}$.

$R$ is clearly an equivalence relation, so we can consider the quotient by this equivalence and denote it $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

($\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, \times$) is a monoid and it is easy to see that there is a well-defined map that sends the equivalence classes $[x], [y]$ to $[x\times y]$. Finally we see that the canonical quotient map $f: (\mathbb{Z}, \times) \to (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, \times)$ is a morphism of monoids, and this means that $f(x\times y) = f(x)\times f(y)$.

This involves a lot of handwaving, but formalising it is not that hard and I didn't want to do it since it seems you are not interested in having a proof, but I hope you get the point of this agument and how it answers your question.